# Saving lines that are skipped by pd.read_csv into a separate DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Code example:

```
data = 'a,b,c\n1,2,3\n4,5,6,7\n8,9,10'
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), error_bad_lines=False)

Skipping line 3: expected 3 fields, saw 4
```

What I want here is to get the skipped lines and save them elsewhere like another DataFrame or Array.

The length of each file I actually deal with is about 8K rows with 4 to 12 columns and the skipped lines have certain information which I DO NOT want to lose.

I tried to use

```
try:
   pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), error_bad_lines=False)
except(pd.parser.CParserError)
```

How do I catch the "Bad Line"?

One of the files: http://www.pjm.com/pub/account/loadhryr/1998.txt

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the Official(tm) approach is, but I often pass `names` and then do my postprocessing.  For example:

```
>>> pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=["a", "b", "c", "other stuff"], skiprows=1)
   a  b   c  other stuff
0  1  2   3          NaN
1  4  5   6            7
2  8  9  10          NaN
```

after which you can use boolean filtering like `df[df['other stuff'].notnull()]` to select the ones with extra data.

I've even done things like

```
>>> pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), names=range(10), header=None)
   0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0  a  b   c NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1  1  2   3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2  4  5   6   7 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3  8  9  10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

to get started in the past, but then you have to make sure that you convert the dtypes appropriately at the end so you don't have slower-perfoming objects when you could have floats.  I usually only use this as an intermediate step, though, and immediately write out a better-formatted csv, so it doesn't matter much.

(I've wanted a "lossless" data reading method where you don't care about performance, you just care about getting all the data in, but for all I know there's one already there.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  The "names" approach works for the files with same format, while as the format of raw data files changes(the number of columns increases, so as the Bad lines), I have to manually adjust the length of names to read in all the data.  I am wondering is there a way I can automatically adjust the names parameter or I just set up a large enough range like 100.

Again, thank you so much for your help!